# fullcalendar: eventLimitClick -- execute a url

Tags: url, fullcalendar

On the "+17 more" link, I want it to open a url of my chosing for that specific date.  I'm not finding the documentation to have an example, and I know this must be really easy (because everything else has been!).

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

```
    eventLimitClick: function(cellInfo) {
        if (cellInfo.date) {
            var newdate = moment(cellInfo.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
            window.open('url-i-am-calling?variables, "_blank");
            return false;
        }
    },
```